# I do not succeed in trapping an OperationalError from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, error-handling, sqlalchemy

This is my first question here, I hope I do it in the right way. If not, please tell me so I can improve.

I have an SqlAlchemy database with my books. I made an python application with a tkinter GUI. In that GUI it is also possible to enter your own query. The query should then be excecuted and the result is shown within the application.
Because it is possible to submit a completely wrong query, for instance: "lkjsdgf",
I would like to catch that situation. I am quite new to programming an Python, and I have read a lot about error handling here on SO, but also on several online learning sites. Based on the information, I would expect that this code would catch the error (to be sure I even ended with except Exception as e):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy
import sqlite3

# This creates a SQLite :memory: database: 
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

# Here I simulate a wrong input from the user
zoek = "kjlk"

try:
    engine.execute(zoek).fetchall()
except OperationalError:
    print("Operational error")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Unknown error")
```

But instead, the error is not trapped and I get an extensive traceback. This is (last) part of it:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "kjlk": syntax error
>   [SQL: kjlk] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        13 try:
>        14     engine.execute(zoek).fetchall()
>   ---> 15 except OperationalError:
>        16     print("Operational error")
>        17 except Exception as e: NameError: name 'OperationalError' is not defined

The link in the trace back text also does not help me and I could not find an answer in SO, so I decided to make a new question. I hope I can get the answer here and learn a little bit more: "what should I do to catch the error(s)?"

Comment: Could you please format the error to it is readable?

Comment: What it seems to say is that `OperationalError` is not known - did you forget to import it? Or you could just use `sqlite3.OperationalError`, as you already import `sqlite3`.

Comment: Where do you import `OperationalError` from? It is not visible in your code example.

Comment: @Scott Hunter: I formatted the error by typing 2 spaces after each line (my input had normal line breaks). Does it always get mixes up when posting?

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
...
except OperationalError:
```

https://www.fullstackpython.com/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-examples.html